# Ignoring N/A value while using arrayformula in Google SheetsHi al

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, sum, array-formulas, na

At the moment I'm working to make a sales report. In this report I have to sum up different values in several columns. To do this I use an arrayformula since the sheet is getting longer day by day.

The main problem is that in some of the columns there are N/A values. That makes it hard to do the calculation because if one of the calculated cells has an N/A value the total amount will not be calculated. Is there a trick to avoid this and don't calculate N/A values and still use the arrayformula?

I tried `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A<>"", IFNA(A2:A+B2:B+C2:C, ""), ""))` but I keep getting the N/A errors. The basic present formula I use is: `=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"", A2:A+B2:B+C2:C, ""))`

Link to [**example spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19CHn_0PBMXsLwkxbDme54XmgrPsimgL_/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113473184069413619756&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Hope someone can help. Thanks!
[UPDATE] Adjusted link

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", A2:A+B2:B+N(C2:C), ))
```

your N/A is not a valid error but a text string. `N()` will convert anything to a number.

[image]

or try the new way:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",, BYROW(A2:C, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, it works! I will have to dive deeper into the new LAMBDA function. Thank you so much!